# creating mysql table and loading data

Tags: mysql, unix, warnings, bioinformatics

I am facing a problem.

I have this data. The data is stored gene_ontology.txt that was extracted from:http://gala.bx.psu.edu/downloads/hg15/genes/
In this data, in the second column there are multiple strings, "-", ",", and whitespaces between strings and numbers as well.

TO EXAMPLE THE DATA:

```
GO:0000001,mitochondrion inheritance
GO:0000002,mitochondrial genome maintenance
GO:0000003,reproduction
GO:0000005,ribosomal-chaperone activity
GO:0000006,high affinity zinc uptake transmembrane transporter......
```

I want to insert that data in a table that I had created as follow:

```
mysql> create table annotation
    -> (GOid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    -> FUNCTION TEXT NOT NULL,
   -> PRIMARY KEY goid (goid));
```

when I loaded:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'gene_ontology.txt' INTO TABLE annotation FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Query OK, 26077 rows affected, 1639 warnings (0.89 sec)
Records: 26083  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 6  Warnings: 1639  (<- LOADING GAVE ME WARNING AND SKIPPED RESULTS)
```

The result for:

```
mysql> SELECT GOid FROM annotation LIMIT 6;
```

show good results

```
+-------------+
| GOid        |
+-------------+
|  GO:0000001 |
|  GO:0000002 |
|  GO:0000003 |
|  GO:0000005 |
|  GO:0000006 |
+-------------+
```

[image]

but, the problem is when I select both columns:

```
mysql> SELECT GOid, FUNCTION FROM annotation LIMIT 10;

+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| GOid        | FUNCTION                                                        |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
                                     |nce
                              |enome maintenance
                                                  |
                                  | activity
  |GO:0000006 | high affinity zinc uptake transmembrane transporter activity
      |000007 | low-affinity zinc ion transmembrane transporter activity
                                               |
|  GO:0000009 | alpha-1                                                        |
                     |hexaprenyltranstransferase activity
                                       |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

or only the second:

```
 +----------------------------------------------------------------+
 | FUNCION                                                        |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------+
                                      |
                               |nce
                                                  |
                                  |
 |igh affinity zinc uptake transmembrane transporter activity
 |ffinity zinc ion transmembrane transporter activity
                                                   |
 | alpha-1                                                        |
                     |stransferase activity
                                           |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[image]

I don't know what is happening.
To solve, I have been tried to change the type of "FUNCTION", using LONGTEXT and also BLOB.
I have done these changes as I considered that the problem lied on type of the second column(FUNCTION). 
But I had not succeeded.

Comment: Can you please output of `head gene_ontology.txt`. add in your post by editing

Comment: Function, funcion? Which?

Comment: And be advised that FUNCTION became reserved in 8.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the comma "," in-between second column's text.

Try to load the complete file as fixed width into a single column in `TableA`. Then use `substr()` to put the first field in the second table `TableB's` column1, while the 2nd field into column2.

This may load the data and you can analyze the data further to improve loading process.